# How to parallelize nested for loops on a GPU in Python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, gpu

### Question

I have three nested for loops and would like to run them in parallel on my (CUDA-capable) GPU using Python 3.6. The order of evaluation doesn't matter, but the outputs must be stored. How can I do this? Notice the range for each for loop is different.

### Code

```
def f(i, j, k):
    if i < j < k:
        return np.log(1 + i + j + k)
    else:
        return (i, j, k)

for i in range(1000):
    for j in range(2000):
        for k in range(3000):
            f(i, j, k) # Save the output???
```

### Extra Details

Is this even possible to be parallelized on a GPU? What packages can I use? How can I store the outputs without having to wait for other loops to compile? Should I just append `[i, j, k, f(i, j, k)]` to a list and put them into an organized array later? If the output of `f` is `float16`, the output volume easily gets out of hand. How can I overcome that? The function above is made up so it would have mixed form arguments, if statements, and call a NumPy function purely for educational purposes.
If using for loops is not the right approach, please enlighten me. Should I perhaps create a list of all possible `(i, j, k)` and send a few thousand to GPU to evaluate it? Please consider memory limitations. Even storing 100 x 200 x 300 integers on memory is expensive.

### Outside the box

How can I convert this problem to a linear algebra problem so I can take advantage of Numpy or Numba?

Comment: Not many algorithms are cubic. What are you trying to implement?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I just need to evaluate a complex function called [3-j symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-j_symbol) for lots of i's and j's and k's. At this point I don't care about the underlying problem, I want to learn how to call a function on nested for loops and store them.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. **Congratulations** on winning **[ The Most Questions Asked At Once ]** ... have never seen so many questions put under one StackOverflow post. **How computationally expensive** -- in **`[us]`** -- is the call to the **`f( p1, p2, p3 )`** ? Post the code of the `f( p1, p2, p3 )`, as **both `[TIME]`-domain and `[SPACE]`-domain costs** do matter -- + otherwise you risk some more strict members will claim the code is not an MCVE-formulated problem definition ... so better review your post in this direction.

Comment: The package you're looking for (and several other answers) can be found by searching for [NVidia's **PyCUDA**](https://developer.nvidia.com/pycuda).

Comment: @user3666197, it's an honor! hehe! I updated the code and the reason I am asking so many questions is to get things started. And to communicate that what I care is a general solution for nested loops for complex functions. I'm also throwing my ideas out there so people can comment on different approaches. Once this question has been answered, I will edit the question to something more reasonable.

Comment: Why not have one thread iterate the loop and put each iteration into a queue. Then a second thread could process the queue asynchronously. Depending on where the bottleneck is you can add more threads to either the iteration or the processing.

Comment: Have you ever solved this?

Comment: Since then, I have learned that I must convert my problem into arrays and pass them to the GPU. So, 1 loop can become a 1D array, two loops, a matrix, .... I hope that helps.